# Exploding file name to find match

Tags: php, regex, explode

I am looking to determine the best way to dig out a portion of a file name. I'm putting together an application that needs to be able to explode a file name and then query a database based on a portion of that file name. Let me give you some examples of how the file name may come in.

```
Station-[_A]_Warren_2014-01-2614_40_01_377000.mp3
Fire_station_2014-02-1311_10_01_347000.mp3
FIRE_EMS_2014-03-0111_11_01_212000.mp3
Really_long_name_goes_here_2014-04-0123_12_01_177000.mp3
```

Right now, my variable after scanning a directory to find the long file name is $file. I need to figure out a way to possible explode those pieces (which I can do the explode) but I need a good way to help determine the "front" of that file name. The front of that file name is defined as "anything before the *YYYY-MM-DDHH*" format.

So I am guessing that there has to be some sort of regex or pre_match done on this?

Comment: What is the meaning of 377000, 347000, 212000, 177000?

Comment: Everything after the _2014 is a date/time format, all the way down to milliseconds. So _2014-04-05-23_13_01_120000.mp3 is April 5th, 2014, at 11:13:01:120000

Comment: And I suppose you want to convert it to timestamp to put it in the database?

Comment: What about the part before that, I mean **Station-[_A]_Warren_** as in the first case.

Comment: Nope - I want to get the name before the _2014. For this application, that beginning file name is matched to something in the databaes "just as it is"

Comment: This web application is tying into a piece of software. So when they name their listing in the software, it converts it to a unique format, like: Station-[_A]_Warren. In my web application, they do the same thing, thus making it a "match" of names, and then activating things further. But I need to figure out how to get the Station-[_A]_Warren (or whatever variation) extracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

```
preg_match('/(.*)(_\d{4}-\d+-\d+)_(.*)/', $file, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks Andy - that looks like it will do the trick! I will have to test it some, but should be just fine!

Comment: Great answer. Declaring the `$matches` isn't necessary though.

Comment: And wow! Double thanks Andy! I've never done any preg_match where I've ever used anything other than $matches[1]. This time, I get to use $matches[2] and $matches[3] as well :D

Comment: @RPM - for the sake of my own ignorance, why not?

Comment: `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )` It is passed in by reference. Therefore it is accessible in scope after [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) returns.

Comment: @RPM You're right. I removed the line declaring $matches. Thanks.